# Customer has multiple rows and want to combine them in Excel

Tags: excel

I have order data that breaks up orders by each individual item in the user's cart. This means that if a customer purchased 3 items, then they would have 3 rows in my spreadsheet. What I'm hoping to do is ONLY have 1 row per customer. Below is what my data *currently* looks like:

```
Customer Name       Item Number      Item
Derek               1                Shirt (Blue)
Derek               2                Shirt (Red)
Derek               3                Shirt (Yellow)
Amy                 1                Shirt (Red)
Amy                 2                Shirt (Yellow)
```

I would ideally like my data to looks like the following:

```
Customer Name       Item              Item 2              Item 3
Derek               Shirt (Blue)      Shirt (Red)         Shirt (Yellow)
Amy                 Shirt (Red)       Shirt (Yellow)      BLANK
```

I have roughly 1000 customers in this dataset and around 5000 rows currently. Is there any way I can do this in Excel? My idea is creating a new table with a column named "Customer Name" and columns named "Item 1", "Item 2", etc. In the item 1 column, I use a formula that looks for the Item name if Customer Name in my new table matches the customer name in my original table AND the item number = 1. Then do the same for column "Item 2". I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need formula to filter data based on condition. You can use `AGGREGATE()` function with `INDEX()` formula to filter data based on condition to achieve your desired result. As per below screenshot put below formula to `B10` cell then drag across down and right as need.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$6)/($A$1:$A$6=$A10),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

[image]